# Swift Core Data optional attribute with Scalar Type gets evaluated to 0 not NIL

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I need to have an entity with an Optional Float attribute (with no default value). E.g:

```
<attribute name="price" optional="YES" attributeType="Float" usesScalarValueType="YES"/>
```

After I store a record in the DB  with this price being NULL, I want to retrieve it and map it to one of my DTOs, but surprise, it's evaluated to 0 (I was expecting NIL)

After looking into the core data auto-generated entity, I find that it was generated as non optional:

```
@NSManaged public var price: Float
```

Now, I understand why NULL becomes 0, but the question is more on how to make this model Optional.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can add some extension based on `value(forKey:)`, something like the following

```
extension YourClass {
    var isPricePresent: Bool {
        self.value(forKey: "price") != nil
    }
}
```

Note: I assume it is due to legacy & backward compatibility - internal containers just cannot store nil and optional is not Objective-c compatible type.